# How to scroll down in CTkScrollableFrame using arrow keys in custom tkinter

Tags: python, customtkinter

Am writing a program that in python using customtkinter. It has a CTkScrollableFrame in it but to scroll one has to use the mouse. Is it possible to use the arrow keys instead and how?

I've looked for solutions but they only apply to tkinter not customtkinter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that customtkinter does not provide a "formal" way to do so, but of course you could just use the function they used to make the widget scroll.

```
frame._parent_canvas.yview("scroll", 1, "units")
```

This moves the scroll bar 1 unit down. Then bind it to keys like this:

```
from customtkinter import CTk, CTkScrollableFrame, CTkButton

root = CTk()

frame = CTkScrollableFrame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for n in range(30):
    CTkButton(frame, text=f"Button {n}").pack()


speed = 10
frame.bind_all("<Up>", lambda event: frame._parent_canvas.yview("scroll", -speed, "units"), add="+")
frame.bind_all("<Down>", lambda event: frame._parent_canvas.yview("scroll", speed, "units"), add="+")

root.mainloop()
```

Now the widget will move up and down "speed" units using up arrow and down arrow keys.